# Angular 2: pipes - How to format a phone number?

Tags: angular, pipes-filters

I've searched here and there, and I am not able to find something specific about formatting a phone number.

Currently, I am retrieving phone numbers form a JSON in the following format:

25565115

However, I want to achieve this result:

02-55-65-115

For that, I believe that I need to use a custom pipe and I don't think that there is a built-in one that does it automatically.

Can you please give me some guidance on how to do so?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g29gfr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

`pipe` implementation in **TS** would look like this

```ts
import { Pipe } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "phone"
})
export class PhonePipe {
  transform(rawNum) {
    rawNum = rawNum.charAt(0) != 0 ? "0" + rawNum : "" + rawNum;

    let newStr = "";
    let i = 0;

    for (; i < Math.floor(rawNum.length / 2) - 1; i++) {
      newStr = newStr + rawNum.substr(i * 2, 2) + "-";
    }

    return newStr + rawNum.substr(i * 2);
  }
}
```

---

Declare the PhonePipe in your NgModule's declarations

---

### Usage:

```ts
import {Component} from 'angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    Your Phone Number: <input [(ngModel)]="myNumber" />
    <p>
      Formatted Phone Number: <b>{{ myNumber | phone }}</b>
    </p>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  myNumber = "25565115";
}
```

There are many things that can be improved, I just made it work for this particular case.

Comment: I your component where you pass `PhonePipe`, don't you have to import it first like this? `import {PhonePipe} from './pipe'`

Answer (score 21):

Building on "user5975786", here is the same code for Angular2

```ts
import { Injectable, Pipe } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "phone",
})
export class PhonePipe {
  transform(tel, args) {
    var value = tel.toString().trim().replace(/^\+/, "");

    if (value.match(/[^0-9]/)) {
      return tel;
    }

    var country, city, number;

    switch (value.length) {
      case 10: // +1PPP####### -> C (PPP) ###-####
        country = 1;
        city = value.slice(0, 3);
        number = value.slice(3);
        break;

      case 11: // +CPPP####### -> CCC (PP) ###-####
        country = value[0];
        city = value.slice(1, 4);
        number = value.slice(4);
        break;

      case 12: // +CCCPP####### -> CCC (PP) ###-####
        country = value.slice(0, 3);
        city = value.slice(3, 5);
        number = value.slice(5);
        break;

      default:
        return tel;
    }

    if (country == 1) {
      country = "";
    }

    number = number.slice(0, 3) + "-" + number.slice(3);

    return (country + " (" + city + ") " + number).trim();
  }
}
```

Comment: This works much better than the accepted one. I works perfectly for me after I trim all the extra characters by using `var value = tel.toString().trim().replace(/^\+|-|\(|\)/g, '')` instead.

Answer (score 19):

When formatting phone numbers from a JSON data service, this was the simplest solution I could think of.

```
<p>0{{contact.phone.home | slice:0:1}}-{{contact.phone.home | slice:1:3}}-{{contact.phone.home | slice:3:5}}-{{contact.phone.home | slice:5:8}}</p>
```

This will format "25565115" into "02-55-65-115"

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Nice and simple!

Comment: KISS, Keep ISS.

Answer (score 15):

I just bumped myself on [this article](https://medium.com/@Pierre_anthill/angular-2-4-pretty-phone-number-pipe-2da3fab8fe6e) showing how to do that using a **Google's lib** called [libphonenumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libphonenumber-js). It seems they use this lib in many different languages and has a very wide support (the link is just to the JS package version). Here's how I've implemented it to portuguese / brazilian phone numbers:

**First:**

```sh
npm i libphonenumber-js
```

**Then:**

```sh
# if you're using Ionic
ionic generate pipe Phone

# if you're just using Angular
ng generate pipe Phone
```

**Finally:**

```ts
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { parsePhoneNumber } from 'libphonenumber-js';

@Pipe({
  name: 'phone'
})
export class PhonePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(phoneValue: number | string): string {
    const stringPhone = phoneValue + '';
    const phoneNumber = parsePhoneNumber(stringPhone, 'BR');
    const formatted = phoneNumber.formatNational();
    return formatted;
  }
}
```

You can implement many different ways with this lib. There's many, many handy methods on it, you can just go reading and see how it suits you.

**Thumbs up** if you've liked. =]

Comment: true, it's reckless to use a formatter of 10 lines' code. there's so much to phone numbers in terms of regions and rules... we should probably use google's lib. I used it a few years back and there were many details I learned while implementing it

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution with regex to convert the number 25565115 to this 02-55-65-115

```
import { Pipe } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "phone"
})
export class PhonePipe {
  transform(value: string): string {
    return value.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{3})/, '0$1-$2-$3-$4');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use something like that in a custom Angular2 pipe:

```ts
switch (value.length) {
  case 10: 
    country = 1;
    city = value.slice(0, 3);
    number = value.slice(3);
    break;
  
  case 11: 
    country = value[0];
    city = value.slice(1, 4);
    number = value.slice(4);
    break;
  
  case 12: 
    country = value.slice(0, 3);
    city = value.slice(3, 5);
    number = value.slice(5);
    break;
  
  default:
    return tel;
}
```

Check this AngularJS out for more info, but as I said you need to convert it to Angular2:

http://jsfiddle.net/jorgecas99/S7aSj/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'usPhone'
})
export class USPhonePipe implements PipeTransform {
  private readonly PHONE_REGEX = /^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/;
  private readonly PHONE_PREFIX = /\+?(1)?/;
  private readonly SPACES = /\s+/g;

  transform(value: string): string {
    let trimmed = value.replace(this.SPACES, '');
    trimmed = trimmed.replace(this.PHONE_PREFIX, '');

    const matches = trimmed.match(this.PHONE_REGEX);

    if (!matches) {
      return value;
    }

    const phoneParts = matches.slice(1,);
    return phoneParts.join('-');
  }
}
```

But in my case I needed it to be like: +19998887766 -> 999-888-77-66