# Align Phone Number With Angular Pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I am trying to beautify phone number(999 999 9999) and display with Angular Pipe. Is there is any pipe to do that? Please help me out

**TS**

```
public phone;
this.phone = 9999999999;
```

**HTML**

```
<h1>{{phone | ?? }}</h1>
```

Comment: Check out this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36895431/angular2-pipes-how-to-format-a-phone-number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with angular ‘slice’ pipe. 
Exp:

> `{{ phone | slice:0:2 }} - {{ phone | slice:3:5 }}`

like that...