# How to show the data filter by regular expression in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on Angular 7 project. I have a Config.json which has some regular expression as shown below. I have some static data which i want to filter and show to match regular expression.

Config.json

```
{
"myregExp" : "[0-9],\\d,\\d,-,[0-9],\\d,\\d,\\d,\\d,\\d,-,[0-9],\\d,\\d"
}
```

samplepage.component.html

```
<h1>{{sampledata}}</h1>
```

sample.component.ts

```
this.sampledata= "123456789321";
```

I want the output as 
123-456789-321

I tried to use like this

## {{sampledata | filter : myregExp}}

which is not working. Can someone help me please. I am new to angular/javascript.

Comment: need custom pipe in this case

Comment: i know that is what my question is. what is that custom pipe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Align Phone Number With Angular Pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54806689/align-phone-number-with-angular-pipe)

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54806689/align-phone-number-with-angular-pipe

Comment: i cant use slice:0-2 because it should come from config.json

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by creating Custom Pipe.

Create Pipe and Add it in AppModule inside `declarations` array:

So in this case AppModule.ts Code looks like:

```
import { CustomPipePipe } from './app/custom-pipe.pipe';

@NgModule({
  ......
  ......
  declarations: [CustomPipePipe],
  ......
})
```

Custom pipe Code:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'customPipe'
})
export class CustomPipePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    var disco = this.AddDashes(value, 3, 6).join('-')
    console.log(disco)
    return disco;
  }


  AddDashes(str, firstGroup, SecondGroup) {
    var response = [];
    var isSecondValue = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i += firstGroup) {
      if (!isSecondValue) {
        firstGroup = 3;
        response.push(str.substr(i, firstGroup));
        isSecondValue = true;
      }
      else {
        response.push(str.substr(i, SecondGroup));
        isSecondValue = false;
      }
    }
    return response
  };
}
```

And use it in HTML Like:

```
{{ your_value | customPipe}}
```

[`WORKING_DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fpnv7f-qvts9d)

Comment: var disco = this.AddDashes(value, 3, 6).join('-') In this line 3 and 6 are static. I cant use this. My regular expression can be anything, Custom pipe should be flexible to match any REGULAR EXPRESSION.

Comment: @rakesh I think you can't modify the string by using Regex!