# How to create filter for any regular Expression

Tags: html, angular, filter

I am working on Angular 7 project. I have regular expression which is configured in config.json file.

I want the common filter solution to match the data with regular expression and show that data biding with regular expression.

Example:
If Regular expression is : [0-9],\d,\d,-,[0-9],\d,\d,\d,\d,\d,-,[0-9],\d,\d
Data: 123456789321
**Output should be : 123-456789-321**

If Regular expression is : [0-9],\d,\d,-,[0-9],\d,\d
Data: 123456
**Output should be : 123-456**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show the data filter by regular expression in Angular 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56142435/how-to-show-the-data-filter-by-regular-expression-in-angular-7)

Comment: i dint get the solution

Comment: Hmm let's hope!

Comment: If you talk about using a pipe to filter your data, [don't](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe).

Comment: hve you try ngx-mask ? https://jsdaddy.github.io/ngx-mask-page/main

Comment: ngx-mask doent support regular expression

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
try https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask with regular exp.

```
  data = '123456789321';
  constructor() {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getStr('[0-9],\d,\d,-,[0-9],\d,\d,');
    this.getStr('[0-9],\d,\d,-,[0-9],\d,\d,\d,\d,\d,-,[0-9],\d,\d,');
  }

  getStr(regStr) {
    const parts = regStr.split('-,');
    let prevLen = 0;
    let str = '';
    parts.forEach((part, index) => {
      let len = part.split(',').length - 1;
      str = index === 0 ? `${this.data.substr(prevLen, len)}` : `${str}-${this.data.substr(prevLen, len)}`
      prevLen = prevLen + len;
    })
    console.log(str);
  }
```

Comment: can u create this example in stackblitz for better understanding

Comment: const parts = regStr.split('-,'); this is again static. you are splitting by hyphen. My RegExp can be anything, it can have (,),$,#,@...