# Can i use function inside curly braces in angular?

Tags: angular

I have students.component.html

```
<div *ngfor=“let student of students”
<p> {{ student.phoneNum }} </p>
```

displays: +12345678980
students object is coming from students.component.ts
i want to display it as (234) 567-8980

how can i format it inside {{ }} ? can i use {{ formatNum(student.phoneNum) }} ? please suggest the best way to perform this.

Comment: Use a pipe: https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Comment: You could do it. However, it's not considered a good practice to call functions from templates. For this particular scenario, you'd need an Angular pipe.

Answer (score 2):

Try use pipe, see [Angular2 {pipes} - How to format a phone number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36895431/angular2-pipes-how-to-format-a-phone-number)

Also you can handle it by call function As below:

```
<p [innerHtml]=formatNum(student.phoneNum)></p>
```